# Delphi: discrete bottom axis in TChart

Tags: delphi, teechart

i'm not able to implement a discrete bottom axis with `TChart` (i'm using lite version in XE5)

My purpose is to display 2 series: 
Series1 : `TBarSeries`, 
Series2: `TLineSeries` scalar

in a chart with Bottom Axis **DISCRETE** (integer values or date)!

Adding these values (for example)

```
Series1.addXY(0,2,'',clGreen);
Series2.AddXY(0,5,'', clRed);

Series1.AddXY(1,4,'',clGreen);
Series2.AddXY(1,5,'', clRed);

Series1.AddXY(2,6,'',clGreen);
Series2.AddXY(2,2,'', clRed);
```

the chart is drawn as follows:

[image]

But, as you can see, the bottom axis is not discrete. I want to obtain something like this

[image]

How can i achieve that? Thank you.

Comment: If you mean that the stairs should be applied with an offset (-0.5) then do `Series2.AddXY(xVal-0.5,yVal,clRed);`.

Comment: I'm not sure if TeeChart Lite has it, but if you don't want spaces between your bars, then a `TAreaSeries` in "stairs" mode is what you're looking for. When using many values, a `TAreaSeries gives better looking results than a `TBarSeries``.
Furthermore, I don't think even have to fall back to a `TLineSeries` for what you're after. You can simply create another `TBarSeries` or `TAreaSeries` with thick border lines and no filling.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a simple example using a `TAreaSeries` and a `TLineSeries`, both with Stairs and I  think this looks as you'd like it to:

```
uses Series;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
const values0: array[0..2] of TChartValue = (2, 4, 6);
      values1: array[0..2] of TChartValue = (5, 7, 2);
var i: Integer;
begin
  Chart1.View3D:=false;
  Chart1.Legend.Visible:=false;

  with Chart1.AddSeries(TAreaSeries) as TAreaSeries do
  begin
    Color:=clGreen;
    Stairs:=true;
    UseYOrigin:=true;
  end;

  with Chart1.AddSeries(TLineSeries) as TLineSeries do
  begin
    Color:=clRed;
    Stairs:=true;
  end;

  for i:=0 to High(values0) do
  begin
    Chart1[0].AddXY(i-0.5, values0[i]);
    Chart1[1].AddXY(i-0.5, values1[i]);
  end;

  Chart1[0].AddXY(Chart1[0].Count-0.5, values0[Chart1[0].Count-1]);
  Chart1[1].AddXY(Chart1[1].Count-0.5, values1[Chart1[1].Count-1]);
end;
```

[image: Area and Line]